# How to get methods like onPageFinished, onPageStart from chrome powered flutter_custom_tabs in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-chrome, webview

1.Below is the code snippet to open url using chrome supported webview - flutter_custom_tabs.

2.I want to do some functionality on url content so I need those methods onPageFinished, onPageStart and the webview should be chrome powered webview.

```
    try {
      launch(url,
          customTabsOption: CustomTabsOption(
            toolbarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          enableDefaultShare: false,
          extraCustomTabs: const <String>['org.mozilla.firefox', 'com.microsoft.emmx'],            
      ));
    } catch (e) {          
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
```